# Использование Vue.js в blade laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

В шаблоне blade подключил через cdn vue.js

Все работает, но когда пытаюсь вывести к примеру значение свойства то laravel ругается с ошибкой

Use of undefined constant message - assumed 'message'

Вот мой код (vue подключен точно корректно)

```
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="container">
<p>{{message}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data:{
        message: 'Количество нажатий по кнопки'
      },
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно добавить `@` перед текстовой интерполяцией **Vue.js** или для больших частей кода использовать директиву `@verbatim`

```
@verbatim
    <div class="container">
       {{message}}
    </div>
@endverbatim
```

Документация [Blade & JavaScript Frameworks](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#blade-and-javascript-frameworks)